# Eloquent relationship causes model nesting

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the Eloquent *BfsImages* model defined with the following relationship:

```
public function listing()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CommercialPeople\Models\BfsListings', 'bfs_listing_id', 'bfs_listing_id');
}
```

And the attribute appended:

```
public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return config('settings.bfs_image_path') . $this->listing->auth_agent_id . '/' . $this->filename;
}
```

As you can see the attribute refers to the parent model, so when I call the following:

```
BfsListings::with('images')->all();
```

Even though technically the relationship **from** images **to** listings is not called, because of that reference in the custom attribute BfsListing model is appended to images which causes model nesting so I get BfsListing->BfsImages->BfsListing.

My question is, is there a way to refer to parent model without actually appending it and returning it's data? Or.. perhaps there is a better way to maybe pass a variable from the parent to the child so that it could be used without calling the relationship back again?

To be honest since all my models are cached I don't care that much about multiple queries back and forth, I just want to remove the unnecessary data from images model, however I could use some smart way around it to not duplicate the query.

**Edit**

its possible to refer to other models without using the relations like this:

```
$this->listing()->setEagerLoads([])->first()->auth_agent_id;
```

However this still means that the reference to the parent model will be made once, which again causes two level nesting (so basically problem is not solved, but in some cases this will help to avoid infinite loops).

I still can't figure out how to call the parent model without actually loading it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the parent -> child relationship then access the parent via the alias.

```
$a = $parent->child;
$b = $a->parent;
```

Comment: And how exactly will that work? I load the model by the following: `$bfs = BfsListings::with('images')->find($id); $bfs->setAppends(['listed_date']); return $bfs;`